# What would be the XPath for this XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Probably question is very simple but i just stuck with this ...
I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InfoLinkDocument>
  <HAWBUpdate>
    <HAWBNumber>41665496563</HAWBNumber>
    <HAWBDetails>
      <HAWBWeight>2.56</HAWBWeight>
      <HAWBWeightUnit>KG</HAWBWeightUnit>
    </HAWBDetails>
  </HAWBUpdate>
</InfoLinkDocument>
```

And i have the following in my XSL file

```
<xsl:template match="/InfoLinkDocument">
  <xsl:for-each select="HAWBUpdate">
    <xsl:variable name="HAWBNumber" select="/HAWBNumber" />

    <xsl:variable name="HAWBWeight" select="./HAWBDetails/HAWBWeight" />
    <xsl:variable name="HAWBWeight2" select="//HAWBDetails/HAWBWeight" />
    <xsl:variable name="HAWBWeight3" select="HAWBDetails/HAWBWeight" />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

But for some reason `HAWBWeight`, `HAWBWeight2` and `HAWBWeight3` are empty. Why ? What XPath should be in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xslt looks okay. You likely incorrectly refer to your variables later in the code.

Here is the test

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/InfoLinkDocument" >
  <xsl:for-each select="HAWBUpdate">

    <xsl:variable name="HAWBWeight" select="./HAWBDetails/HAWBWeight" />
    <xsl:variable name="HAWBWeight2" select="//HAWBDetails/HAWBWeight" />
    <xsl:variable name="HAWBWeight3" select="HAWBDetails/HAWBWeight" />

    HAWBWeight: <xsl:value-of select="$HAWBWeight"/>
    HAWBWeight2: <xsl:value-of select="$HAWBWeight2"/>
    HAWBWeight3: <xsl:value-of select="$HAWBWeight3"/>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    HAWBWeight: 2.56
    HAWBWeight2: 2.56
    HAWBWeight3: 2.56
```

tested in http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: yes, you are right. I used Visual Studio for working with XML\XSLT. And for some reason it shows me value for variable `HAWBNumber` and doesn't do the same for another variables, so i thought that XPath is wrong. But it looks like an issue in VS ...